# Filter by virtual column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I have the following database structure :

```
[Order]
OrderId
Total

[Payment]
OrderId
Amount
```

Every Order can have X payment rows. I want to get only the list of orders where the sum of all the payments are < than the order Total.

I have the following SQL but I will return all the orders paid and unpaid.

```
   SELECT o.OrderId, 
          o.UserId, 
          o.Total, 
          o.DateCreated, 
          COALESCE(SUM(p.Amount),0) AS Paid
     FROM [Order] o
LEFT JOIN Payment p ON p.OrderId = o.OrderId
 GROUP BY o.OrderId, o.Total, o.UserId, o.DateCreated
```

I have tried to add Where (Paid < o.Total) but it does not work, any idea?
BTM I'm using SQL CE 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the HAVING clause.

Instead of "Where (COALESCE(SUM(p.Amount),0) < o.Total)", try "HAVING (COALESCE(SUM(p.Amount),0) < o.Total)"

Check out the [MSDN Reference on HAVING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180199%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: You can reference a column alias in the HAVING clause, instead

Comment: If I add HAVING (Paid < o.Total) to my query I get : Major Error 0x80040E14, Minor Error 25501

There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 5,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = GROUP ]

Comment: user329957: Could you paste in the entire query?  The error message is vague.  Also, the link I supplied in my answer has some sample SQL that you could take a look at.

Comment: Cyrena: SELECT o.OrderId, o.UserId, o.Total, o.DateCreated, COALESCE(SUM(p.Amount),0) AS Paid
FROM [Order] o
LEFT JOIN Payment p ON p.OrderId = o.OrderId
HAVING (Paid < o.Total)
GROUP BY o.OrderId, o.Total, o.UserId, o.DateCreated

Comment: user329957: HAVING is placed after GROUP BY.  Take a look at the reference link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Order.* From Order
Left Join
(Select OrderID, Sum(Amount) As t From Payment Group By OrderID) As s On s.OrderID = Oder.OrderID
Where IsNULL(s.t,0) < Order.Total
```